# throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

hey guys i know this has been asked before but i do not understand it ,,
so anyone help please

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const api = require('./server/routes/api');
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/todo')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', api);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/todo/index.html'));
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log('server started'));
```

the error i get when starting the server

```
throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
```

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, you need to pass a function.  What is `api`?

Comment: yup got it ,, thanks